# Последовательный парсинг с помощью Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup, веб-скрейпинг

Здравствуйте. Предположим, что у меня есть html файл, в нём есть вот такой кусок разметки

```html
<div class="class_Name">
"Любой неизвестный текст"
<img src="link_To_Image">
"Снова незнакомый текст"
</div>
```

Как при помощи Jsoup последовательно спарсить текст и картинку в таком же порядке? Важно  помнить, что это только часть разметки, и в теге div может находится ещё множество различного контента.

```java
Element element = document.select("div.class_Name").first();
Elements elements = element.children();
```

Таким способом я могу выделить только теги внутри класса class_Name, но текст при этом игнорируется.
**Важное уточнение: проблема не в том, чтобы спарсить картинку, а в том, чтобы сделать это последовательно с текстом.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я узнал, как это сделать.
Делается это вот таким способом:

```
List<Node> nodes = element.childNodes();
        for (Node n : nodes) {
            System.out.println(n);
        }
```

Будет выведено:

```
"Любой неизвестный текст"
<img src="link_To_Image">
"Снова незнакомый текст"
```

Источник:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44195443/sequential-parsing-with-jsoup